# Как передать id и name button-а из html в js объект?

Tags: javascript, html

Помогите пожалуста. Имею такую ситуацию, есть две кнопки с разными `name`-ами и `id` в HTML файлe, мне нужно передать `id` и `name` этих двух кнопок в js и добавить их в объект (желательно реализовать это сразу в виде предачи в объект).
Любая помощь будет полезна, заранее спасибо.

```
<ul>
  <li><button name="button1" id="1">ButtonOne</button></li>
  <li><button name="button2" id="2">ButtonTwo</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: При клике записывать в объект или  нет? Уточните вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var obj = {};
var el = document.querySelectorAll('ul li button');

for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    obj.id = e.target.id;
    obj.name = e.target.name;
    console.log(obj);
  });
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><button name="button1" id="1">ButtonOne</button></li>
  <li><button name="button2" id="2">ButtonTwo</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо брат, очень помогло, просто мне нужен был только передать данные в js без клика.

var objData = {};
var buttonData = document.querySelectorAll('ul li button');

for (var i = 0; i < buttonData.length; i++) {
  objData.name = buttonData[i].name
  objData.id = buttonData[i].id
  console.log(objData);
}

Comment: @AlisaBondarchuk, рад, что сумел помочь. Для избежания непониманий в будущем у отвечающих, составляйте вопрос более конкретно, со всеми мелочами, пожалуйста.

Comment: Брат, просто такая ситуация, что я сам с трудностью понимаю что мне нужно(ну точнее не мне, а им), но со временем всю будет чётко.

Comment: Возникл один нежданчик, слушай, можешь сказать как передать все значения цикла в объект глобальной видимости?

Comment: @AlisaBondarchuk, можно использовать список `attributes` у элемента и закидывать всё в объект, который **НЕ** находится в конструкции `function` (это и есть глобальный объект/переменная)

Comment: И всё-таки вот уже сколько часов голову ломаю над этой фигнёй, но не без результата. Мне вот что нужно, нужно эти взять все id и name всех кнопок с классом .btn-p и передать их в внешний объект, к которому я могу получить доступ, но как всю это реализовать не понимаю. Мне потом этот объект нужен, чтобы из него извлекать id и name для поиска.

Answer (score 0):

Mне удалось найти решение, вот как оно выглядит

[...document.getElementsByClassName('btn-view')].reduce((a, c, i ) => (a['H' + i + ' - h ' + i] = {name: c.name, id: c.id}, a), {}); console.log(objData);